# Unable to run Yii migration

Tags: yii, yii2

I run few commands :

```
yii migrate
```

and

```
$ yii migrate/data templatedata
```

```
$ php yii migration/data templatedata
```

but all of the command that i run return the value :

```
bash: yii: command not found
```

I have Composer installed.

The command should create migration script with the data from table.

[my team already create a previous migration script on his pc and push to gitlab. but in my side, i just want to update the data. so it will update too in the script.]

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags, or explain how this problem is related to Gitlab (which is a software not running on your own computer) or Composer (which is a package installer, not anything related to your bash not being able to run commands)

Comment: Is `yii` executable available in the folder you're trying to run this command from? Make sure you're calling the correct script. And provide more details (output of `ls` at least) if you still need assistance with that.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `php yii migrate` or `./yii migrate` from the root folder of the project